# Autofilling column (or row) referencing an (autofilled) row (or column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

While using excel, let's say I want to autofill a column starting from A2 that references a row from cell A1 to, say, E1.

But if I were to drag the autofill from the cell A2, defined by "=A1" I would get a column that looks like: "=A1" , "=A2" , "=A3" , "=A4" , "A5" where I would want the column to be referenced to be like: "=A1" , "=B1" , "=C1" , "=D1" , "=E1". How is this achieved? Merely copying the rows, transposing it into the said column doesn't work for the purpose of this excel sheet.

Comment: Ahh I should add, I'm not looking for a macro solution. If it is the only solution, however, I guess I should accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OFFSET` function. Place this in `A2` and drag down

```
=OFFSET($A$1,,ROW(1:1))
```